# Randomly select file from folder in JS without an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code to randomly grab a file from a folder path, and load it via jQuery:

```
var path = '/path-to-files/',
files = ['1.php', '2.php', '3.php', '4.php', '5.php', '6.php'],
i = Math.floor(Math.random()*files.length);
var url = (path+files[i]);
$("#my-div").load(url);
```

It's great, it works well. But I would prefer a method to randomly grab files from the `path` without building an array. Is that possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't get a list of files from a directory using just JavaScript(jQuery is JavaScript), it would have to be handled from the server. You could request a server-file that then returns the content of a random file from a directory.

Answer (score 5):

```
var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
$("#my-div").load('/path-to-files/' + i + '.php');
```

Comment: What if I did not want to specify a max limit on files (in this example, 6)?

Comment: @Yahreen: You mean a random number from `1` to `Infinity`?

Comment: This is just as hardcoded as what he had in the original question.

Comment: @Yahreen: You're saying you want filenames from the server without having a collection present in the scripting environment?

Comment: @user1689607 yes, it sounds like I will need a server solution for my problem. Thank you.

Comment: @jholloman: Yep, looks like you're right. I totally missed the point. +1 to you and the other guy.

Comment: With this approach you'll never be able to access the 1st file in the list - IE '0' will be returned when you always add 1

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to make a server request to get the array of possible files. This is the only way to do this without sticking to a naming convention or a set list of files.